# How to POST an image like a web form in node.js / server side with cookies set

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, multipartform-data

Huge thanks in advance for any help. I just can't figure out how to both add cookies and post as multipart/form-data

I'm using [mikeal/request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) but the example (at the bottom of the page) of posting a multi-part POST only accommodates urlencoded data. The readme shows how to use the node-form-data library to send form-data POSTs, but does not show a way to set cookies. Hence my great confusion.

Here is my code:

```
  var options = { method: 'POST', uri: 'http://www.abcd.com/upload_photo_iframe.html?format=json',
        form: {}, multipart: [
            { 'name': 'upload_photo',
                'content-type': 'image/jpeg', body: file_blob
            }
        ]
    }

    var cookie = request.cookie('S=' + sessionKey);
    options.jar = request.jar();
    options.jar.add(cookie);

    request(
        options
        , function (error, response, body) {
            console.log(error,response,body);
             //API responds with error because request is application/x-www-form-urlencoded, instead of multipart/form-data

        }
    )

}
```

If this is not a good question for SO let me know in the comments and I will delete it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You *could* set the cookie manually:

```
request.submit({
    host: 'www.abcdef.com',
    path: '/upload_photo_iframe.html',
    port: 80,
    headers: {
        'Cookie': 'S=bj8lc76u9221pq6nkbjhdsnbv6'
    }
}, function(err, res) {
    ...
});
```

But I would just use the [`request` module](https://github.com/mikeal/request), which handles both file uploads and cookies.

Comment: Thanks - this helped me clarify the problem. I updated the question in response.